# Dropbox Api Tutorial "Error: Cannot find module"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to follow this Dropbox API tutorial in VS Code but I have hit wall and I am not sure what to do.

I am currently to this point. https://youtu.be/AzCQrjWQJs4?t=596

When I run the debugger tool in VS Code I get the following error.

```
/Users/dragon/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node Web/Dropbox-test/Expense-Organizer/Dropbox-SDK-Test.html
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60286/6bfc7c65-ef7c-44dc-a026-aa4eaa801b84
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/dragon/Documents/2020/Mosaic/Web/Dropbox-test/Expense-Organizer/Dropbox-SDK-Test.html'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1065:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:911:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Process exited with code 1
```

My setup.

- VS Code
- Node JS
- Setup the project folder and installed Dropbox SDK

[image: Folder Structure][image]

index.js

```
import { Dropbox } from 'dropbox';
const dbx = new Dropbox({
  accessToken: 'MY TOKEN GOES HERE',
  fetch
})

dbx.filesListFolder({
    path: ''
  }).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Dropbox SDK Test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dropbox JavaScript SDK</title>
  <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am pretty new to this.
Is anyone able to point me in the right direction as to what I am missing / not understanding?

When I run the Dropbox-SDK-Test.html file via VS Code live server I get the following error in chrome console.
[image]

Comment: How are you trying to load the HTML file?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I am running the Node.js Debbuger tool in VS Code that is generating the cannot find module error. But I am also loading the HTML file via VS Code Live Server which opens in Chrome and generates the Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "dropbox". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue.
Using the example request code provided by the official Dropbox Git rather than the tutorial solved the issue.

```
var fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
var Dropbox = require('dropbox').Dropbox;
new Dropbox({
    fetch: fetch,
    accessToken: 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE'
})
  .filesListFolder({path: ''})
  .then(console.log, console.error);
```

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/tutorial-JavaScript%20SDK.html